# Server-side REST paypal doesn't work : executePayment method doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I've got a problem with the Execute payment method with Paypal. I'm trying to integrate the Server-side Rest on my Asp.net MVC application. I've a problem with this method :
In the server side, I've this method which supposed to receive a paymentId and a payerID.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult executePayment(string paymentId,string PayerID)
    {
        // Authenticate with PayPal
        var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
        var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);

        var payment = new PaypalTransactions();
        PaypalTransactions.ExecutePayment();

        return Json("okadaokd", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In the client side, I've this script :

```
<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
        commit: true,

        // payment() is called when the button is clicked
        payment: function() {

            // Set up a url on your server to create the payment
            var CREATE_URL = 'localhost:59679/Home/createPayment';

            // Make a call to your server to set up the payment
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_URL)
                .then(function(res) {
                    return res.paymentID;
                });
        },

        // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            // Set up a url on your server to execute the payment
            var EXECUTE_URL = 'localhost:59679/Home/executePayment';

            // Set up the data you need to pass to your server
            var data = {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID: data.payerID
            };

            // Make a call to your server to execute the payment
            return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_URL, data)
                .then(function (res) {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

The payment method on the client side works well but the onAuthorize doesn't work. I've this code errors :
-MLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:59679/Home/createPayment. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
-Uncaught Error: Request to post localhost:59679/Home/createPayment failed: [object ProgressEvent]

What's the solution ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried adding "http://" at the beginning of your CREATE_URL and EXECUTE_URL variables? Since it says that the cross site origin requests are only supported by HTTP calls, I'm guessing that it's not detecting it as an HTTP call.

Comment: I already tried that, but it's still doesn't work

Comment: Just to be sure. You're making the AJAX calls with "http://" at the beginning, but is the html file containing your javascript being served over HTTP as well? I mean, if you look at your url, does it look like "http://localhost:59676/SendRequests" or it look like "file://SendRequests.html"? Because you also need to load that page over HTTP to make it work.

Comment: Yes, the HTML file is containing my javascript. My url look like : http://localhost:59679/Home/Panier